# Autocomplete getting data from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, redux, google-places-api

I want to create an autocomplete input component that retrieves places from Google Maps Place API.

This is a sample response from this API:
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchResponses

My question is how should I handle user input / typing and calling the API to update the autocomplete options?

Would it be correct to do something like:
On `keyup` set a timeout, to check if the user stopped typing, then call the API after a few seconds; and on `keydown` clear the timeout to avoid calling the API while the user is still typing?

**I don't have access to Google Cloud Platform Console, so I can't enable Maps Javascript API and use [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete)**

Comment: There is a really well coded mixed JS & Jquery example in [TokenInput from James Smith](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/). It's not React but should translate. I had to do something similar a few years back and found reading the source of this work very informative. You may also be able to adapt it to talk to your target API. Worth a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using pure javascript?
If not, yout could use lodash [debounce function](https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce), it does exactly what you need.

**EDIT:**
As someone pointed out in the comments, i shouldn't just post a link as an answer, so i'll provide a snippet to help improve this answer

```
import _ from 'lodash';
$(selector).on('keyup', _.debounce(function (e) {
      // stuff
    }
}, 500));
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21202202)

Comment: Thanks @OmarEinea! This is my second answer on stackoverflow, so i'll keep this in mind!